# When is concurrent execution of two critical sections producing results in some unknown order useful?

Tags: operating-system, critical-section, thread-synchronization

Refer to Galvin et. al Operating System Concepts, 8th edition, 6th chapter, section 6.9, page 257. It says, "If two critical sections are instead executed concurrently, the result is equivalent to their sequential execution in some unknown order. ***Although this property is useful*** in many application domains, in many cases we would like to make sure that a critical section forms a single logical unit of work that either is performed in its entirety or is not performed at all." When is that property useful? Please explain, thanks in advance! Also, please offer me some vegemite to eat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is useful (because it increases potential parallelism) when the order that the critical sections are executed is irrelevant.

For a more complex example; let's say you have a thread fetching the next block from a file, a thread compressing the current block, and a thread sending the previously compressed block to a network connection.

In this case there are obvious constraints (you can't compress the current block while it's still being fetched, and you can't send the compressed block to a network connection until it's finished being compressed), but there are also obvious opportunities for parallelism where the order is irrelevant (you don't care if the next block is fetched before or after or while the current block is compressed, you don't care if the current block is compressed before or after or while the previously compressed block is being sent to network, and you don't care if the next block is fetched before or after or while the previously compressed block is being sent to network).